# itextsharp how to add line height to the chunk content

Tags: c#, .net, itext, pdf-generation

I am using the following code in .net using iTextSharp

```
PdfPTable Header2 = new PdfPTable(2);
Header2.DefaultCell.Padding = 4;
Header2.WidthPercentage = 90;
Phrase pp4 = new Phrase();
pp4.Add(new Chunk("  Text of the first line\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 17, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK)));
pp4.Add(new Chunk("  Text of the second line", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 15, iTextSharp.text.Font.ITALIC, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK)));
PdfPCell hcell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(pp4));
hcell3.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
hcell3.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
hcell3.BorderColor = iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK;
hcell3.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(255, 255, 255);
Header2.AddCell(hcell3);
```

The output shows text very close to each other in various lines. I need to put up some vertical space between two lines.
How can I achieve this in the code above?

Answer (score 2):

The space between the lines is called the *leading*, referring to the small strips of lead that were put between different lines of type in the early days of printing.

You have two options.

If you are using `PdfPCell` in text mode (in case you didn't know: you do), you can change the leading like this:

```
PdfPCell hcell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(pp4));
hcell3.Leading = 20;
```

If you are using `PdfPCell` in composite mode, you can change the leading like this:

```
pp4.Leading = 20;
PdfPCell hcell3 = new PdfPCell();
hcell3.AddElement(pp4);
```

In the former case, you work with a single `Phrase` in the cell, and all the content of that cell takes a single value for the leading. In the latter case, the leading of the cell is ignored. Instead the leading of the objects you are adding to the cell (using the `AddElement()` method) is used. In the latter case, it's possible to use more than one leading in the same cell.

Please not that you're using an old version of iText. We don't call it iTextSharp anymore, we call it iText for .NET. The most recent version is 7.1. If you're just starting, **please upgrade** as old versions of iText are no longer supported for users who aren't a customer. See the [iText for .NET download page](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET).